# Freeing memory in openCL freezes my computer

Tags: c++, opencl, grand-central-dispatch

I have 3 nested loops, the top most and the inner most loops are thread safe, but the middle loop is not.  I'm essentially operating a non-linear function on each column of a big matrix multiple times.  I need to loop over the columns, then the iterations of the function, then the rows.

I'm using a MacPro with Xcode, Grand Central Dispatch and openCL.  I have a few options of how to do this.  1) I can use the CPU to loop over the columns in parallel and do the other 2 loops with just for's.  2) I can use openCL on my GPU to loop over the rows in parallel (doing the others with for loops) or 3) if I'm lucky I can use the CPU to do the top most loop in parallel, and openCL to do the inner most loop in parallel.  I tried the third choice because if it works it will be the fastest, hopefully...

so I did

```
dispatch_apply(ncol,cpu_queue,^(size_t col){  // outermost column loop
    void* gpu_mem = gcl_malloc(...);          // send column to GPU
    dispatch_sync(gpu_queue,^{                // tells it to do stuff on GPU
        for (int t = 0; t < nt; t++){         // loop over iterations of function
            function_kernel(&range,...);      // openCL loop over the rows
        }
        gcl_memcpy(...);                      // send results back to CPU
    });
    dispatch_release(gpu_queue);              // release the queue
    gcl_free(gpu_mem);                        // free the gpu memory
});
```

This code freezes my computer, I have to hard shutdown by holding the power button on the box.  I've identified the culprit...gcl_free(gpu_mem);... If I comment this out then the code works fine.  But this whole thing is actually inside a bigger for loop.  So the code above works for 2 or 3 iterations of the big outside loop but then the gpu runs out of memory because I'm not freeing it.  If I change the first dispatch_apply to a for loop everything works fine too and I can free the gpu memory without a problem.

I think my computer is smart enough to run an openCL loop inside of a dispatch parallel loop efficiently because this code (without the gcl_free) is significantly faster than using a for loop over the columns.  My GPU has somewhere around 2000 cores and I'm using ~100 worker groups so I don't think that's a bottle neck.  It's just having a problem freeing the gpu's memory inside a parallel loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Docs say code in the dispatch_apply block needs to be reentrant safe. Maybe gcl_free isn't? You could try queueing the gcl_free calls e.g. dispatch_async them up onto the cpu_queue or dispatch_sync them onto their own queue?

Comment: Thinking some more: If its reentrancy of gcl_free then you probably can't trust gcl_malloc here either. That suggests making a separate queue onto which the gcl_malloc and gcl_free calls can both be dispatch_sync'd.

Comment: @SimonJenkins - I tried a few things.  None of them worked. The first thing I tried was moving the gcl_malloc and gcl_free outside of the dispatch apply.  This didn't kill the code, but it gave the wrong answer.  I guess it doesn't copy the memory for each worker on the dispatch_apply.  I also tried putting the gcl_free inside the gpu's dispatch queue.  That still killed the computer.  Next I tried putting the gcl_free in its own dispatch queue.  This killed the machine.  Next I tried putting everything in the dispatch_apply in another dispatch_sync. Also killed machine.

Comment: Hmmm. I'd have expected your last test to work (though completely undoing the cpu parallelism speedup) if it was just gcl_malloc/free reentrancy. BTW should you be releasing the gpu_queue inside the dispatch_apply like that? If its one queue created outside the dispatch_apply shouldn't it be released once after its all done?

Comment: @SimonJenkins - I forgot to include the declaration of the 

    dispatch_queue_t gpu_queue = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(...);

inside the code I posted, but I am in fact declaring the gpu_queue inside the dispatch_apply in actual code I'm running, so I do need to release it inside the dispatch_apply.  I guess I'll keep playing around with it.  I just wish it didn't freeze my computer so often.

Comment: @SimonJenkins - still don't understand why gcl_free doesn't work in a dispatch_apply, but I eventually found a work around. I use a for loop over the columns but then on the gpu_queue I use dispatch_async instead of sync, and pair that with a dispatch_semaphore_t to tell when the internal stuff in the for loop iterations are done.  I regained the speed I originally saw when I didn't free the gcl memory, I even am doing a little better.  Thanks for your input.  Now if I could only figure out how to use double for math functions in openCL..